# Java binary search array list

Tags: java, binary-search

I'm trying to search for strings in an array list as below which is working fine. But, the challenge is when the string i'm searching for is embedded in between some text example "XXXXTESTXXXX". 
The binary search what i have so far seems to not find it. I have also tried "contains" method but didn't work either. Not sure where i'm i going wrong. Please suggest.

```
Array Content :[PIGEON, XXXBEARXXX , XXXCAT, XXXDOG, XXXELEPHANTXXX , XXXHORSEXXX , XXXLIONXXX , XXXMOUSEXXX , XXXOWLXXX , XXXPARROTXXX , XXXTIGERXXX ]
```

Example search string:-

```
Search String = "BEAR"
```

Code

```
ArrayList File_F1_Array = new ArrayList();  
    // Read the lines of the Source file (File_1) in to Arraylist
    try {
        BufferedReader File_F1_Br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(File_F1));
        while ((File_F1_Line = File_F1_Br.readLine()) !=null ) {
            File_F1_Array.add(File_F1_Line);
        }
        File_F1_Br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }

    // Sort the array list
    Collections.sort(File_F1_Array);

        // Search lines from Refernce file (File_2) in Arraylist
        try {
            BufferedReader File_F2_br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(File_F2));
            while ((File_F2_Line = File_F2_br.readLine()) !=null) {

                int index = Collections.binarySearch(File_F1_Array, File_F2_Line);

                boolean StringCheck = File_F1_Array.contains(File_F2_Line);
                }
```

Comment: Well, what did you expect? Both methods do exact string comparison using `.equals`. You are welcome to write your own linear or binary search that uses `String.contains`

Comment: I think you should convert your list into a *trie* (not to be confused with *tree*) such that you can perform lookup in O(log n) time (with *n* the number of words).

Comment: Binary search doesn't work for finding substrings.

Comment: Can we user binary regex as wild cards ?

Answer (score 0):

your algorithm is not correct! you are searching in array which has "xx..." and you want to get rid of "xx..."s! you have to create another arraylist without "xx.." and put some binding key between 2 arrays in order to keep the first array with Xs.